# Two problems on intellij (mac os)

Tags: java, encoding, jboss, intellij-idea

I have just started testing intellij, and I'm already facing two major problems which I can't figure it out how to resolve:

1. When I deploy my webapp and I access it in any browser all the accents characters are showed as ? (question marks). Same project on same jboss as 7.1.1 standalone shows accents just fine on eclipse (which, btw, I configured the workspace as utf-8).
2. When I start jboss in debug mode an exception keeps get being thrown and nothing works.

Any ideas? I thought this would all work out of the box, mainly because everybody says so many beautiful thinks about intellij.

Comment: You should specify the exception thrown in part 2

Answer (score 0):

For part 1, check File > Settings > File Encoding. I'm not experiencing this, and I see I have everything set to UTF-8 and auto-detect.

No idea on part 2. :)